possible to create custom type hint creation functions?
I am playing around with creating a tool that can detect the addition and subtraction of incompatible dimensions (of unit-bearing values) at type checking time. It would need to know how to combine dimensions correctly when they are multiplied and divided.
As a part of that effort, I'm trying to get this code type check the way I want both in mypy and pycharm:
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')


def f(item):
    return float


class C(Generic[T]):
    def g(self) -> f(T):  # mypy says f(T) should be f[T] (mypy is wrong :) )
        ...


a = C().g()
a  # pycharm knows this is a float!!

The goal here is for the type checker to be happy, and to know that a is a float.
This is just a simple example showing the kind of thing I'm trying to figure out.
Mypy doesn't like it because normally you don't see syntax like f(T) as a return type. However it works fine in pycharm (pycharm knows that a is a float). I understand this is probably just because mypy is pretty strict and pycharm is much more forgiving.
I tried turning f into different things to get the f[T] syntax to work- such as a dict, or a class that allows usage of __getitem__, but mypy is still unhappy, AND pycharm doesn't know a is a float in those cases.
EDIT: From the comments I now understand that a function call as a type hint is a serious no-go because function calls are a 100% runtime kind of thing. So if I'm going to do this I need to find a way to stick to the standard type hint [] syntax.
EDIT: For those interested: I posted about getting language support for an idea like this on python discuss. Turns out it would probably require a lot of complex features to be added to the python type system.

MORE ABOUT WHY I'M TRYING TO DO THIS
The idea behind all of this is I would create some kind of DimMultiply and also some kind of DimDivide type hint syntax, so that you can write code like this (using 3.12 type hint syntax):
class Value[T]:
    def __mul__[O](self, other: O) -> DimMultiply[T, O]:
        ...
    def __truediv__[O](self, other: O) -> DimDivide[T, O]:
        ...

Since all dimension combinations in principle can be represented as, optionally, a series of multiplications in a numerator, and, optionally, a divide operation with a series of multiplication in the denominator, you could represent any dimension combination with only tokens for each dimension type (Length, Mass, Time, etc etc) and with a single DIVIDE operator (if required).
The DimMultiply and DimDivide syntax would properly combine the dimensions into new tuples of types when they are multiplied/divided. Like this (very very simple):
a: Tuple[Length]
b: Tuple[Length]
c: Tuple[Length, Length] = a * b

But to generalize this behavior across all kinds of dimension combinations, I'd need to write some kind of DimMultiply and DimDivide function/type that magically creates the types, and for the type checker to recognize the result coming from that function/type:
>>> DimMultiply[Tuple[Length, DIVIDE, Time], Tuple[DIVIDE, Time]]
Tuple[Length]

With that kind of tool in place, you could use the type checker to detect incompatible dimension errors, like this:
from my_unit_library import ft, lbs

x = 1*ft
y = 3*lbs
z = x + y  # type checker throws error here

The type checker would know that the type of x is something like Tuple[Length], and the type of y is something like Tuple[Length, Mass, DIVIDE, Time, Time] (which is a force), and that you can't add those two unlike types together.
However this __mult__ and __truediv__ return type syntax isn't working in either pycharm or mypy at the moment. If I write it in the function call way, however, pycharm seems to work, at least sometimes.
Bottom line: is there some kind of method I am missing for customizing the behavior of type checkers, so that it would know to "drill down" into something like DimMultiply[Tuple[Length], Tuple[Length]] and return Tuple[Length, Length] as the actual type?

Well I asked Copilot if there are any type hinting features to make this possible, and it sounds like it's a no go with current tech unless you want to write your own extension to the type checking system.

Type checkers are static analysis tools. Call expressions are dynamic. That PyCharm infers f(T) to be float is non-spec-compliant behaviour, so you can't expect this from other type checkers. If you want your code to also work for people using other IDEs, please stick to the spec.

@InSync thanks for the feedback. This is what I thought. So to get this to work widely I'd need to write my own extension(s) using the type hint syntax (without function calls), popularize it in the scientific computing community, write a PEP, and have it accepted.

It should be noted that a type checker may or may not support plugins. It just so happens that both Mypy and PyCharm does, but this might not be true for others (e.g. Pyright, which is used by VSCode's Pylance).

Apart from the fact that a function is only executed at runtime, and thus it's return value cannot be used for static type checking (as pointed out by the comments on static analysis), does the basic premise even make sense? There's no reason why a distance in feet cannot be multiplied by a weight in pounds (though I wish you'd use metric). The result would be (for example) torque, which is expressed in foot-pounds in the US. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

@Grismar the goal is to disallow adding and subtracting of incompatible units/dimensions at type check time. Multiplication/division is legal and would return a new type every time, hence the need for DimMult and DimDiv.

@InSync if I ever got around to creating this (probably won't; maybe someone will see this idea and be inspired!) the purpose of making plugins would be to get people to like it and use it and maybe eventually it finds its way into an approved PEP.

The Python static typing system neither has concepts of (1) variadic collections of unordered types and (2) type arithmetic; you'll need both to represent a type-safe physical-units library. I can imagine writing a mypy plugin which supports this, so if you really wanted to do this, instead of inventing your own units library, try writing a mypy plugin for a Python library which already exists for handling physical units.

@dROOOze indeed. If I were to do it, I'd do it using pint. To solve the unordered types problem, I would just sort the numerator and the denominator.

I don't think separating the numerator and denominator solves the issue (and in fact makes the typing system more complex, as a denominator is just a numerator to a negative power). The whole concept is, the product of two quantities with scalar dimensions is commutative, so the declaration order of the quantities' dimensions doesn't matter, and the dimensions of the product is a collection of unordered simple dimensions. Multiplying/dividing quantities is just addition/subtraction in the unordered types' exponent field, and addition/subtraction is just equality comparison of unordered types.

@dROOOze separating the numerator and the denominator by itself doesn't solve the problem, but if you separate them AND sort them (separately), I think it does. L^2 is tuple[Length, Length]. L/T^2 becomes tuple[Length, DIVIDE, Time, Time]. If you multiply a pressure times area, the type of the result's dimension property becomes reordered and returned as just a force, Tuple[Length, Mass, DIVIDE, Time, Time]. All dimensions are sorted in the numerator and denominator and the type system can compare them consistently even though you're correct that order doesn't matter for dimensions.

@dROOOze although perhaps instead of a single tuple with the DIVIDE operator I should consider a Numerator and Denominator tuple. So like Tuple[Numerator[Length, Mass], Denominator[Time, Time]] for a force.
